# how to permute two array keys with each other

Tags: php, arrays, permutation

How to combine every value from one array with another to create a structure that would be a source for a table.
Example, we have array:

```
$a = array(
  'animal' => ['horse', 'donkey', 'elephant'],
  'food' => ['grass', 'hay', 'acorn'],
);

And the effect I need is:

$result = array(
  'horse' = array(
    'grass' => [ 'animal' => 'horse', 'food' => 'grass'],
    'hay' => [ 'animal' => 'horse', 'food' => 'hay'],
    'acorn' => [ 'animal' => 'horse', 'food' => 'acorn'],
  },
  'donkey' = array(
    'grass' => [ 'animal' => 'donkey', 'food' => 'grass'],
    'hay' => [ 'animal' => 'donkey', 'food' => 'hay'],
    'acorn' => [ 'animal' => 'donkey', 'food' => 'acorn'],
  },
  'elephant' = array(
    'grass' => [ 'animal' => 'elephant', 'food' => 'grass'],
    'hay' => [ 'animal' => 'elephant', 'food' => 'hay'],
    'acorn' => [ 'animal' => 'elephant', 'food' => 'acorn'],
  },
);
```

But my question is also is it possible to generalize the algorithm to arbitrary high dimensions.

Comment: Have you tried something? Show us your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as algorithms go, I would say attempt something on your own.

That being said, I will suggest starting with nested foreach loops:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($a['animal'] as $val) {
    $result[$val] = array();
    foreach ($a['food'] as $val2) {
        $result[$val][$val2] = array('animal' => $val, 'food' => $val2);
    }
}
```

and then maybe expand on this code to be modular/customizable.